# How does a good "spec" differ from an unclear "pray?"

Tags: communication, sdlc, specs

I am sure everybody knows [the 5Ws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Ws), a formula for getting the "full" story on something which is used in journalism.

Is there a formula like this -I mean, like that questions should be answered for example- so that a "**spec**" can be considered as totally complete.

Because sometimes I face some features with a spec that sounds like a "pray" more than a specification. -Well, maybe that is even the reason some prays do not come real; specs are not clear enough for the God.

So, what makes a "spec" perfect? Any consensus on this exist?

Thanks,
burak ozdogan

Comment: I didn't know about the 5 Ws. For reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Ws

Answer (score 3):

The only perfect specification is working, running code. Anything else is just an approximation.

Comment: Agreed, unless the code you write ends up solving the wrong problem: http://twiki.org/p/pub/Codev/TWikiMarketingMeeting2008x04x21/software-engineering-explained.png

Comment: -1 I wish I could give you -100 ;-) Seriously; I thought that by now we would've understood that specs and code work at different levels of abstraction. Also, I could argue that it is the *code* what is an approximation of the spec!

Comment: Well, "spec"s are a thing of the past, something primarily used by people still clinging to the old phased waterfall method. User Stories (xp/agile) is the way forward, because they encourages communication and changing requirements by deemphasizing details. And working software (_code_) is what counts in the end.

Comment: @Martin: maybe that's the case in your world. But try to write an avionics or a safe-critical system without a spec! Your disregard for specs makes me laugh, to be honest. It is similar to saying that you can build skyscrapers without blueprints, just because what counts in the end is steel and glass.

Comment: It is well known that one should not compare software development to construction work. It is not the same thing. Development is a non-deterministic process and trying to force that into a world of blueprints and gated phases inevitable leads to failure.

Comment: @Martin: *Some* development is non-deterministic work, and that is not necessarily a good thing. A very large community of software professionals (please see works by e.g. Parnas, or the more recent SEMAT initiative) believe that software development should be deterministic, and that, precisely, it is questionable practices such as "no specs" what make it non-deterministic. Your "it is well known that..." shows that you are still looking at a subset of the real world. But there is a much larger and diverse world out there that does not share your views.

Comment: Software development is akin to "continuous innovation". Every project and product is unique and changing requirements are an integral part of the dev process. It shows that the customer is learning more about her problem and that is a good thing. You cannot change that, no-one can change that. It's just the way it is. It is of no importance if some thinkers thinks i "should be" some other way.

Answer (score 2):

Clear, shared concepts and terminology play a crucial role.

Regarding **terminology**, everybody needs to understand what words mean in the spec. If you are inconsistent with words or use words that the spec's audience will not recognise, then there is a risk of failure.

But that's not all. Even with perfect terminology, you need to have a clear and shared agreement on the **concepts** underlying the words. If differen stakeholders "cut up" reality in different ways, or, in other words, don't see the same things when they look around, and your spec fails to address this, then you are at risk too.

Comment: +1 for terminology.  This is especially important when stakeholders have a domain-specific jargon that is not shared by the software people.  In scientific software, one of the things it seems we need to define every time is what the concept of a "model" means for the given project.

Answer (score 1):

> So, what makes a "spec" perfect?

A specification will never be perfect.  A specification will be good if it answers the who, what, and when questions to everyone's satisfaction.

- Who interfaces with the system?
- What does the system need to do?
- When does the system need to do what?

Answer (score 0):

Peer review also goes a long way. Once you get all stakeholders - including management - to agree on the spec, you can be confident that it is headed in the right direction.

Comment: "As clear and unambiguous as possible" isn't really helpful. The OP wants specific things to look for, not just generalized advice.

Answer (score 0):

Both functional and non-functional (aka [ilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_system_quality_attributes)) requirements have to be considered in order to be complete.

One system that could help is [FURPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FURPS) (or FURPS+).

- Functionality: functional requirements
- Usability: aesthetics and consistency in the user interface
- Reliability: availability ("up time"), accuracy of calculations, and ability to recover from failures
- Performance: throughput, response time, recovery time, start-up time
- Supportability: testability, adaptability, maintainability, compatibility, - configurability, installability, scalability, and localizability

The "+" in FURPS+ to remember concerns such as:

- Design requirements
- Implementation requirements
- Interface requirements
- Physical requirements